# Data loss in disk in linux

Tags: rhel, data-recovery, mkfs

How to get back lost data in `/dev/sde`? I unmounted a mount point on which `/dev/sde` was mounted and ran `mkfs.ext4` as it was not getting remounted and that lead to data loss. Now I can't find `/dev/sde` in `fdisk -l` also. Also, I got a drive failure error.

Comment: You've formatted a full disk (rather than a partition on that disk)?? You might get some of it back with tools like `photorec`, but you might not. Oh, then you've got a disk crash? Sounds like it's time to get out your backups.

Answer (score 0):

If you have some clue of the start-stop addresses of the lost partition 
[rescue option](https://www.gnu.org/software/parted/manual/html_node/rescue.html) of parted can help.

eg if partition was at end of disk

- put start as end of last partition
- end as end of disk

After an mkfs it's considerably harder

But see
[Data recovery from an accidental format on ext4 partition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/168704/323121)